# Sum the first value of each tuple in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

```
x = [(5,3), (8, 3), (7, 3), (5, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
d = {}
[d.__setitem__(d.get(key1,0)+key1,key2) for key1,key2 in x]
print(list(d.items()))
```

I want to add the first value in the tuple having the same second value. I have written the code, but i am not able to find my mistake. 
Any ideas ??

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do, and not sure if your explanation is more confusing than the code or the other way around :) Please elaborate more and add examples of what you want to achieve

Comment: using `__setitem__` in a list comprehension should scream "this is the wrong approach"

Comment: Please provide expected output so that question is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

`__setitem__` returns None, also your logic is wrong too. You need to categorize your items based on the second value then sum their first value up.

You can use `collections.defaultdict()` for categorization:

```
In [13]: x = [(5,3), (8, 3), (7, 3), (5, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4)]

In [16]: from collections import defaultdict

In [17]: d = defaultdict(int)

In [18]: for i, j in x:
   ....:     d[j] += i
   ....:     

In [19]: d
Out[19]: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {3: 20, 4: 10})
```

You could also use `itertools.groupby()` within a dictionary comprehension:

```
In [28]: from itertools import groupby

In [29]: from operator import itemgetter

In [30]: {k: sum(i for i, _ in g) for k, g in groupby(x, itemgetter(1))}
Out[30]: {3: 20, 4: 10}
```

Note that if your list is not sorted based on second item you need to sort it based on that second item before passing to `groupby()` function. (In that case this solution would be so inefficient against the `defaultdict` one)

Answer (score 0):

Kasramvd already has you covered as for why your approach doesn't work. You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group by second tuple elements, then sum the first elements with [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

```
{k: sum(map(itemgetter(0), g)) for k, g in groupby(x, itemgetter(1))}
```

Evidently if your list wasn't sorted by second tuple elements as it currently is, you would have to sort first.

**Demo**

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> x = [(5,3), (8, 3), (7, 3), (5, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
>>> {k: sum(map(itemgetter(0), g)) for k, g in groupby(x, itemgetter(1))}
{3: 20, 4: 10}
```